# Permission denied error for 'go.tools'

Tags: go

When I try to install go tools I am getting permission denied for `/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cover`. I can accept that since it is `/usr/local/` directory and need `root` access.
But my first doubt is why it is trying to install at this location when I set `GOPATH` to some other location.

```
$ go version
go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64

$ export GOPATH='/home/vagrant/repos/atlantis-router/vendor'
$ go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover
go install code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover: open /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cover: permission denied

$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/vagrant/repos/atlantis-router/vendor"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Could anybody guide me solving this issue? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Go tries to install that tool in `$GOTOOLDIR`, not `$GOPATH`, and as you can see it is set to `/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64`. Same thing happens to me here.

just run it with sudo, I guess, since there are other tools in that directory, and I think setting GOTOOLDIR to somewhere else might screw things up.

Comment: Running 'go get' with 'sudo' fail with 'sudo: go: command not found'. I used 'sudo go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover'

Comment: @ram add `/usr/local/go/bin` to root's $PATH

Comment: My $PATH shows me it is included in $PATH. "$ echo $PATH
/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/sbin:....:/usr/local/go/bin". Is it different than what you said?

Comment: what does `sudo echo $PATH` say?

Comment: @ram so just run `sudo -s` and afterwards run go get normally as root

Comment: @ram I just made myself the owner of the go installation: `sudo chown -R mikem:mike /usr/local/go/` to get rid of permissions issues with accessing or changing it.

Comment: @MichaelMügge thanks you so much , change owner of go installation work for me you have been saved my night .

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is a common issue happens for so many users . so happened also to me !
the first step is to set your environment variables for Go by these commands :

```
echo export GOROOT=/usr/local/go >> ~/.bashrc
echo export GOPATH=\$HOME/go >> ~/.bashrc
echo export PATH=\$PATH:\$GOROOT/bin:\$GOPATH/bin >> ~/.bashrc
```

and then go has the accesses
after that run this command so the system considers you as administrator:

```
sudo -s
```

then ctl+Shft+p and select Go: Instal/Upgrade tools

these steps worked for me :)