# I have set my $GOPATH, but it doesn't work

Tags: go

```
$ sudo go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint
package github.com/golang/lint/golint: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

I have set my $GOPATH:
(in `~/.bash_profile` on my Mac)
export GOPATH=$HOME/gocode

And my `go env`:

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/wildcat/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried doing it without `sudo`?

Comment: My problem was [missing xcode licence agreement action](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26197363/1505341) after a clean install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `sudo`: it will use the root environment variable instead of the ones of your account.

You shouldn't need to use `sudo`, as I mentioned in "[How to set GOPATH in Mac OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28741724/6309)":

- `sudo` has a default policy of resetting the Environment and setting a secure path
- unless you use the more complex `sudo -E bash -c 'go get github.com/golang/lint/golint'`):

For now, this should be enough:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint
```

---

The OP adds a *different* `go get` command in the comments:

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover: 
  open /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/cover: permission denied
```

That one would be using `$GOTOOLDIR` (set in your case to "/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64")

As documented in "[Permission denied error for 'go.tools'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273294/6309)", running `sudo -s` then the `go get` command should work.

Comment: `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover: open /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/cover: permission denied` How can I execute commands like this?

Comment: @WildCat: `cmd/cover` is an exception to the rule. You can use sudo, or on osx I prefer to make my go installing writable by my local user account.

Comment: # go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint  ...... I ran this no error but still golint command not found

Comment: @AshishKarpe Maybe because `$GOPATH/bin` is not in your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

sudo according to man:

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or
>        another user, as specified by the security policy.

When using `sudo` you are executing as root. I would suggest that you remove sudo and try executing it.