# Go install copying permission denied

Tags: go, gopath

When running `go install` on my `cmd` folder I get the error:

```golang
go install cmd/go: copying 
/var/folders/wh/9y99138n2w1bvcwxz3tbb8zw0000g
n/T/go-build195667123/b150/exe/a.out: open 
/usr/local/go/bin/go: permission denied
```

It looks like my env variables are set correctly:

```
GOCACHE="/Users/<USER>/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/<USER>/src/unbias"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

Here's my directory of my current project: which is inside my go path:
`/Users/<USER>/src/unbias`

[image]

Since it looks like the permission error is not in my project but in my go install path, I am not sure if I should change ownership of such files.

```
total 37032
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128B Jul 16 15:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel   640B Jul 16 15:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    15M Jul 16 15:52 go
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   3.4M Jul 16 15:53 gofmt
```

My `go.mod` is also:

```
module cmd

go 1.14
```

Comment: The relevant part of the error is `open 
/usr/local/go/bin/go: permission denied`. There are two questions: 1) what is "my `cmd` folder"?; 2) what you're actually trying to do? I mean what you're trying to `go install`?

Comment: @kostix my cmd folder refers to the cmd folder under my current workspace. I am trying to go install just a simple hello world under my current directory which is my current go path I updated the post with relevant info.

Comment: You haven’t shown what GOBIN is set to.

Comment: @JimB GOBIN is not set as per the documentation it should not need to be set for package level `go install` as long as GOPATH is set.

Comment: I understand that, but `go env` will still list it and it appears you are trying to install somewhere you aren’t expecting to

Comment: I see, in `go env` it is `GOBIN=""`

Comment: You also appear to be trying to use GOPATH but it’s set incorrectly. I would suggest bypassing GOPATH and following “How to Write Go Code”

Comment: I have already read through and followed "How to Write Go Code" in which I had it set to `$HOME/go` like they do I have changed it for a specific project to save to the bin under the namespace.

Comment: But you’re not in a valid GOPATH path, and you don’t appear to have a go.mod.

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying I set GOPATH=$HOME and set go.mod with `go init` in the current path. I will update the post with the `cat` of go.mod. But the issue persists if I `go install cmd/` if I first cd into `cmd` and then `go install .` it does install to `$HOME/go` without any issues but it is named `cmd` not `main` it is also not the correct location as I want to install to the bin of my project.

Comment: If I set `GOBIN` to my dir it will save in the bin file but this is not the expected behavior. I am also not able to go install out side of the package directory.

Comment: I think I found the error `go install cmd` was installing something else called `cmd` not my local directory `cmd` in order to solve this I have to cd into the directory and `go install .`

Answer (score 3):

It means that either `<PATH_TO>/cmd` permission is not writable or `$GOPATH/pkg/cmd/go` is not readable for your `User`.

You may:

1. use `sudo chmod -R 777 <PATH_TO>/cmd`
2. using `govendor` or `go mod` if it's outside of `GOPATH`.
3. try to create inside `$GOPATH` instead (you haven't stated if `<PATH_TO>/cmd` inside `$GOPATH`
4. If `<PATH_TO>/cmd` is writable, use `sudo` for now and change the ownership to `<User>` again by `chown`

Check the permission on `<PATH_TO>/cmd` or `$GOPATH/pkg/cmd/go` again by `ls -lah <PATH_TO>/cmd`, it should be readable and writable.

Comment: That would not make much sense as this is a folder inside of my $HOME directory which is under my $GOPATH. CHMOD 777 on my current path did not work but I do have full permissions.

Comment: what do you mean by chmod 777 on your current path not working? can you share the permission of your GOPATH by ls -lah ?

Comment: Oh by that I mean that after using chmod 777 and having full permissions in my directory it still throws the same error.

Comment: Have you tried recursively with -R? I suspect one of your library inside main.go have wrong permission or you haven't set PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin or you haven't set $GOTOOLDIR=/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64" (check it on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273053/permission-denied-error-for-go-tools/27273294#27273294)

Comment: My GOTOOLDIR is `GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"` I did set the path recursively with -R. I think the issue is with permissions on my root folders `/usr/local`

Comment: Try it, and if it works then write your answer and mark it solved so others can relate to this question